# How do I initialize a double array of Circle Objects in a JavaFXML controller with two scenes?

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I’m coding with `JavaFXML` and `Gluon Scene Builder 8.0.0` to create a pixel editor app.  I have created two .fxml files, one for drawing tools (`sample.fxml`) and the other for an array of Circle Objects (32 x 32) that represents a pixel array of LEDs (`PixelEditor.fxml`).   Both share the same controller (`Controller.java`).

I can’t initialize my `Circle[][]` array in `Controller.java` when the user clicks on a menu item like `32h x 32w`.  I used a 4 x4 array to test my code:

```
public void handleMenuAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

   if(event.getSource() == menu32hx32w) {

  Stage pixelStage = new Stage();
  Parent pixelRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("PixelEditor.fxml"));
  Scene pixelScene = new Scene(pixelRoot);
  pixelStage.setTitle("Pixel Array: 32h X 32w");
  pixelStage.setScene(pixelScene);
  pixelStage.setX(0.0);
  pixelStage.setY(0.0);
  pixelStage.show();

  Circle[][] pixelArray = {
       {R0C0, R0C1, R0C2, R0C3},
       {R1C0, R1C1, R1C2, R1C3},
       {R2C0, R2C1, R2C2, R2C3},
       {R3C0, R3C1, R3C2, R3C3},
    };
   }
}
```

If I print out the array I get:

```
pixelArray:
null null null null 
null null null null 
null null null null 
null null null null
```

When I had only one .fxml containing all the Objects I could initialize the pixelArray.  I use fx:id to reference the Circle Objects but placing them in a separate Stage and Scene seems to de-reference them and create a null elements.

What am I not doing?

Previously, with one .fxml file, all I needed to assign values to the Circle Objects was to reference their fx:id in the Controller.java as follows:

```
@FXML
private Circle
R0C0, R0C1, R0C2, R0C3,
R1C0, R1C1, R1C2, R1C3,
R2C0, R2C1, R2C2, R2C3,
R3C0, R3C1, R3C2, R3C3;
```

This is what I'm still doing but the assigned properties via the fx:id reference don't seem to connect?

The PixelEditor.fxml is quite large because I have 32x32 = 1024 Circle Objects even though I'm just testing with the first 4x4.  The code for the first row looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane fx:id="panePixelLayout" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="776.0" prefWidth="776.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <VBox prefHeight="776.0" prefWidth="776.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;">
            <children>
                <HBox prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="776.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;">
                    <children>
                        <Circle fx:id="R0C0" fill="DODGERBLUE" onDragDetected="#onDragDetected" onMouseClicked="#pixelClicked" onMouseDragEntered="#onMouseDragEntered" onMousePressed="#onMousePressed" radius="8.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" style="-fx-fill: DARKGREY;">
                            <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="8.0" top="8.0" />
                            </HBox.margin>
                        </Circle>
                        <Circle fx:id="R0C1" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="22.0" onDragDetected="#onDragDetected" onMouseClicked="#pixelClicked" onMouseDragEntered="#onMouseDragEntered" onMousePressed="#onMousePressed" radius="8.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" style="-fx-fill: DARKGREY;">
                            <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="8.0" top="8.0" />
                            </HBox.margin>
                        </Circle>
                        <Circle fx:id="R0C2" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="22.0" onDragDetected="#onDragDetected" onMouseClicked="#pixelClicked" onMouseDragEntered="#onMouseDragEntered" onMousePressed="#onMousePressed" radius="8.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" style="-fx-fill: DARKGREY;">
                            <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="8.0" top="8.0" />
                            </HBox.margin>
                        </Circle>
                        <Circle fx:id="R0C3" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="22.0" onDragDetected="#onDragDetected" onMouseClicked="#pixelClicked" onMouseDragEntered="#onMouseDragEntered" onMousePressed="#onMousePressed" radius="8.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" style="-fx-fill: DARKGREY;">
                            <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="8.0" top="8.0" />
                            </HBox.margin>
                        </Circle>
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include your `PixelEditor.fxml` file please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in a related question by jewelsea who provided a most excellent answer at: [Have multiple FXML files (created in SceneBuilder), but only one controller. Does each scene load it's own copy of the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158815/).

By creating two controllers, I was able to initialize my Circle[][] array but now I will have to pass parameters between two controllers as jewelsea describes via links provided.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't actually set values to any of: `R0C0`, `R0C1`, etc. If these variables are set to `null` when you create the array, they will still be `null` *even if you set them later*.

You haven't shown the part of your code where you assign `R0C0`, but most likely, that is where the problem is.

Comment: Previously, with one .fxml file, all I needed to assign values to the Circle Objects was to reference their fx:id in the Controller.java as follows:

Comment: @sgroen [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32339237/edit) that information into your question, don't post it in the comments, please.